# Rails: Wrong number of arguments(given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created checkboxes and I want whenever I check the checkbox a method/action should be called but it's not happing I guess the action remains unfazed and I am getting error.

```
Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0).
```

What I did is!
created a checkbox in show.html.erb

```
<%= @files.each do |key,value|%>
  <%=check_box_tag(:key, key,Repository.process)%>
  <%=label_tag(:key)%>
<%end%>
```

then created a new method named as a process in Repository controller

```
 def process --> error in this line
      end
```

and given a route

```
post 'repositories/:id/process', to "repositories#process"
```

Comment: post the log please where exactly it is breaking

Comment: Post the full log from the `rails server log`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/amitojsingh/376e39e3a1bba0e20a5d4ba7262cd4dc

Comment: Post the code for `process`  action, I can see that in app/controllers/repositories_controller.rb:46 file its showing error, I think you are calling any method, that does not require any argument.

Comment: Already posted. Here is my controller file!. https://gist.github.com/amitojsingh/b4f827ac6601cc86fd703dd19460b706. I am not passing any argument to this method have a look.

Comment: Where you are calling this method?

Comment: In show view whenever a checkbox is checked! posted above! Even If I don't call it, nothing changes error remains there!

Comment: You can do the AJAX call on change of `checkbox`.

Comment: i was thinking to do it with Action cable Is it possible or worthy? and Is checkbox effecting this error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are defining an **action method** in `controller` with name `process` but `process` is an already defined action method in rails **base controller**.

You can override it by providing proper parameters but you cannot create another action method with same name of that.

> http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Base/process

You can achieve the functionality that you want by changing the things like this.

1- Change the name of your action in your `Repository Controller`. Lets name it `generate` so add below function in your controller. (Please remove process )

```
def generate
  // Write your custom code to process the params[:id]
end
```

2- Add this in your `routes.rb` file

```
post 'repositories/:id/generate' => "repositories#generate", as: 'generate_repository'
```

3- Replace your `checkbox` code from

```
<%=check_box_tag(:key, key,Repository.process)%>
```

with this

```
<%= check_box_tag(:param_name, param_value, false, data: {remote: true, method: :post, url: generate_repository_path(id_you_want_to_send) }) %>
```

Thats it! When you will check the checkbox you will receive `param_value` in the `param_name` in the params hash in your action method. You can access it with `params[:param_name]`.

Whenever you will receive any value in `params[:param_name]` this means `checkbox` was being `checked` if value is `nil` that means `checkbox` was `unchecked`

> Please change `param_name`, `param_value` and `id_you_want_to_send` with
>   your desired variables or values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your process method accepts no argument but you are sending the checkbox data to it.

The syntax for the check box tag is like this:

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

You check box tag looks like this:

```
check_box_tag :key, key, Repository.process
```

You are passing an argument to checked which you shouldn't
Maybe you would like to use just check_box:

```
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

Also, to trigger a method call when they click the check box, you have to add a remote: true option and send it via Ajax.

I suggest instead of an actual checkbox using a link as it is easier and cleaner. Hope this helps.